# Excess-3 to binary decoder using unused combinations of the code as don't-care condition

Tags: decoder, binary, karnaugh-map

This problem is from my textbook chapter review question, and it seems a lot different from the example provided by textbook, so I have no idea what to do.

I even have solution manual for this, but still, I'm totally lost.

I drew the table as following:
[image]

I set don't care condition as d(0,1,2,13,14,15).

Textbook solution is:
w(A,B,C,D)=m(11,12)
x(A,B,C,D)=m(7,8,9,10)
y(A,B,C,D)=m(5,6,9,10)
z(A,B,C,D)=m(4,6,8,10,12)

Please help me how to get those min-terms based on what method.
Some min-terms are selected when both excess-3 and binary both have the value of 0. (especially on 'w')

Only one thing I can figure out is how to get the min-terms for 'z' which is z(A,B,C,D)=m(4,6,8,10,12) where I can just place 1 in k-map followed by the value of the last digit on excess-3 table

Comment: Only one thing I understand is how to get the 'z' which is z(A,B,C,D)=m(4,6,8,10,12) where I can just place 1 in k-map followed by the value of the last digit on excess-3 table.

Comment: A Don't Care condition can be true or false as needed.  Do your K-Maps and update your question with what you find.  Sometimes it is just a matter of ignoring a solution and doing it yourself.

Comment: Use karnaughs mapping.For each w,x,y and z.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is correct the answer in textbook:
ex: w(A,B,C,D)=m(11,12)
ur answer like this w(A,B,C,D)=m(8,9),just add 3 to each number and u will get same answer like the book
8+3=11.
9+3=12.

Comment: The numbers can't just b added isn't?

Answer (score 0):

when we find a minterm in w,x,y,z 
the excess binary decimal number is the output 
like we have minterm in w are 9 and 10 and the excess three binary decimal nmbr in front of 9 and 10 are 11 and 12.